# How to reset ListBox.Rows property to default (without hard coding the default value)

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.NET ListBox on a page, and as postbacks occur, I change the items in the list.  If there are >= 10 items in the list, I set the Rows property = 10.  But if there are less than 10 items, I'd like to set the Rows back to whatever the default value is for Rows.

I see from examining the reflected code that the default value is 4, but I'd rather not hard code it to 4 in my code and instead somehow just reset it to the default.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What is `ListBox` in `asp.net`? **Are you sure?**

Comment: @Waqas: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listbox%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fetch the default value during the page's `Init` phase. From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd6at422.aspx):

> In this stage of the page's life
>   cycle, declared server controls on the
>   page are initialized to their default
>   state; however, the view state of each
>   control is not yet populated.

So you can do something like:

```
private int _defaultRows;

protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _defaultRows = yourListBox.Rows;
}

protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (yourListBox.Items.Count >= 10) {
        yourListBox.Rows = 10;
    } else {
        yourListBox.Rows = _defaultRows;
    }
}
```